How to use await request.form() while allowing validation using Form in FastAPI?
I'm writing a middleware for my FastAPI app to log details of each request.
I understand that await request.form() will get the form data of the request.
But I know this will consume all the data, and when FastAPI try to consume it, it will get nothing.
In this way, I cannot use something like def post(id: int = Form(...)) to validate parameters.
How to use form data in different places?
Here is a sample code for testing:
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware('http')
async def _(request, call_next):
    print(await request.form())
    return await call_next(request)


@app.post('/')
async def _(id: int = Form(...)):
    return {'id': id}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port='80')

Then perform the post request by curl script:
curl --data id=1 http://localhost

I get a 422 Unprocessable Entity here.
If print(await request.form()) is commented, then this will be 200 OK.

Does this answer your question?

Using await request.body() as demonstrated in the linked answer above would allow the request to go through without any issues (as well as might be a more suitable approach, if you had various endpoints expecting various kinds of data, not just form-data). What happens when calling await request.form() in the middleware before the request reaches the endpoint is similar to what was described in this answer when attempting to use await request.json() twice.
